# utf-8 and latin-1 won't work while reading a csv file with pandas

Tags: pandas, csv, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I am trying to read a CSV file which includes French characters (like é, à, etc.) and email addresses with pandas.

Encoding with utf-8 gives an error. Encoding with latin-1 eliminates my é.

Any idea what encoding I should use ?

Thanks, 
Chris

Comment: could you show us the Error message?

Comment: What encoding is the CSV actually written in?  To quote the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), "In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.".  We don't have your CSV file, so we have no idea what encoding you should use.

Comment: This is what I should get: ['word with é', 'word with à', 'word with è', 'mail@mail.com']. This is what I get when I use latin1: ['word with \x8e', 'word with \x88', 'word with \x8f', 'mail@mail.com']. And this is the error I get when I use utf-8: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8e in position 10: invalid start byte

Comment: My CSV file is created with an excel sheet in MAC > save as "Comma Separated Values (.csv)"

Answer (score 5):

```
pd.read_csv(csv_file, encoding = 'iso-8859-1')
```

where 'iso-8859-1' is the encoding needed to properly represent languages from occidental Europe including France

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# coding: utf-8
import pandas
file_content = open('some_file.csv')
data = pandas.read_csv(file_content, encoding='utf-8', quotechar='"', 
delimiter=';')
```

Comment: The OP specifically said UTF-8 throws an exception.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian. This did not work unfortunately.